# On the effect of dummies on a scaled time series for a forecasting task

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, normalization, forecasting

I have a dataset consisting of 3 variables: a time series related to hourly energy load (expressed in thousands of MWh), a dummy variable related to business hours (e.g. the dummy is 1 the current hour is between 9-18, 0 otherwise) and one for weekend days (e.g. the dummy is 1 if it's Saturday or Sunday, 0 otherwise). I want to perform a forecasting task on the energy load time series using the other two dummy variables as covariates. The forecasting will be performed with neural nets.

If I normalize the time series variable to a -1,1 scale (e.g. using a MinMax scaler), will the effect of the dummies be different in the prediction? What is usually the correct approach in these cases?

Note: the time series is stationary

So far I tried using an LSTM model normalizing the time series to a -1,1 scale, whose predictions are then scaled back to the original scale and confronted to the test data. The code is the following:

```
# train/test splitting and preprocessing

def create_sliding_window(data, window_size):
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(data)-window_size-1):
        X.append(data[i:i+window_size])
        y.append(data[i+window_size])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

n_train = 10000 #lenght of the train period
n_test = int(len(data)-n_train)
sequence_length = 24

features = ['hourly_energy_load']
original_array = data[features].values

# Fit Scaler only on Training target values
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(original_array[:n_train].reshape(-1,1))

# Transfom on both Training and Test data
scaled_array = scaler.transform(feature_array)

X_train, y_train = create_sliding_window(scaled_array[:n_train], sequence_length)
X_test, y_test = create_sliding_window(scaled_array[n_train:], sequence_length)

loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
metric = [tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()]
lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(
              lambda epoch: 1e-4 * 10**(epoch / 10))
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)


# model building

lstm = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

lstm.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metric)

# train/val

history = lstm.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2)

# prediction 
predictions = lstm.predict(X_test)

# I transform the forecasts to the original scale
predictions_scaled_back = target_scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

truth = original_array[-len(predictions):] # I'm obtaining the equivalent of y_test before normalization

rmse = sqrt(np.mean((predictions_scaled_back - truth)**2))

# after that I just plot the truth and scaled predictions
```

I apply this model in forecasting the time series alone, then forecasting adding only the weekend dummy and then adding only the business hour dummy. I get respectively the following plots (the pics). Why am I getting so much overfitting? Am I setting the wrong parameters or should I run the model on the non-scaled time series when including dummies?

[forecasting only the time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXWEZ.png)

[forecasting the time series including the weekend dummy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx13M.png)

[forecasting the time series inclding the business hour dummy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3pmj.png)